# Capacitor livereload not working

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

I can't figure out how to use livereload with ionic 4 and Capacitor on ios.

I'm running this command
     `ionic cap run ios -l` which add my local ip address to `capacitor.config.json`.

however, it seems like I'm missing something in here.

Note: according to [Provide live-reload functionality #3130](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3130)  this should work.

my environment setup:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.2

   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.3

   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.3

   @angular/cli               : 6.1.3

   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.6

   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.5

Capacitor:

   capacitor (Capacitor CLI) : 1.0.0-beta.6

   @capacitor/core           : 1.0.0-beta.6

System:

   NodeJS : v9.10.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)

   npm    : 6.4.0

   OS     : macOS High Sierra
```

Comment: thanks to Julio Cesar for pointing this out, this turned to be a bug in Capacitor which has a PR already https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/741 and https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/742

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Julio Cesar form ionic team for pointing this out, this turned to be a bug in Capacitor which has a PR already [github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/741](http://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/741) and [github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/742](http://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/742)

Comment: this is now merged and released in 1.3.0

Answer (score 14):

For those still struggling with his try:

`ionic capacitor run ios --livereload --external`

It will open Xcode automatically. Run your project and livereload should work.

Make sure that you are connected to the same WiFi on your device and computer.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me as well until I added `"cleartext": true` to `capacitor.config.json` under `server`. Like this:

```
"server": {
  "url": "http://192.168.1.68:8100",
  "cleartext": true
}
```

This is explained in the [official documentation under Using with Framework CLIs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/live-reload#using-with-framework-clis).

Answer (score 1):

Your assets may need to be rebuilt & plugins resynced.

```
npm run build
ionic cap sync
```

Sync will tell you if your Capacitor version matches your platform versions and if there are any issues with plugins.

*Then livereload run with:*

- ANDROID:

```
ionic cap run android -l --external
```

- iOS:

```
ionic cap run ios -l --external
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match below json with your capacitor.config.ts and then run

> ionic cap run android -l --external

```
{
  appId: 'com.app.android,
  appName: 'MYapp',
  webDir: 'www',
  android: {  },
  ios: {  },
  plugins: {
    CapacitorHttp: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  },
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
    url: "http://192.168.1.68:8100",
    cleartext: true
  },
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  loggingBehavior:'debug',
}
```

Comment: I think inside server url, androidScheme  and cleartext is enough to start live reload.
By the way its working fine. 
Thank you.