# Capacitor live reload is not working with Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I need to set up Capacitor live reload with the Angular app. i..e this is not an Ionic app. I have tried this doc: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/live-reload#using-with-framework-clis

But I cannot achieve what I need. Any clue?

I test this on an Android device with OS Android 8.00

I have run the app using `ng serve`

*capacitor.config.json*

```
"server": {
    "url": "http://192.168.x.abc:4200",
    "cleartext": true
  }
```

[image]

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.11
> (C:\Users\Sampath\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
> Ionic Framework               : not installed
> @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1001.1    @angular-devkit/schematics
> : 10.1.1    @angular/cli                  : 10.1.1
> @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.1    @capacitor/core : 2.4.1
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.14.0    native-run  : 1.2.1
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v12.13.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
> 6.12.1    OS     : Windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capacitor livereload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880929/capacitor-livereload-not-working)

Comment: @Akif No. You can see I have done those things and no results yet. This is an Angular app. not an Ionic.

Comment: Did you follow the this instructions? https://capacitorjs.com/solution/angular#install

Comment: @JanithaRasanga Yes that is the first step. I have done the 2nd step too. i.e. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/live-reload#using-with-framework-clis

Comment: In your computer, if you access http://192.168.x.abc:4200 is it working? Maybe your local ip is not correct or you have angular served in a different port. Or maybe your phone is not connected to same wifi as your computer.